# Browserified script not working as expected with Typed.js

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

Working with javascript library from [here](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/master/lib/typed.js). It works as expected , when used without browserify, as it creates global Typed function in browser. But when used browserify with gulp. It's not working as expected, as it not creating global function "Typed", when loaded in browser, throwing error Typed is not function.

in my main script, imported library as below .

```
import 'typed.js/lib/typed.js';
```

Is there anything I missed, or I have to use it some other way?

gulp.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('scripts', async function() {
    browserify('./main.js')
    .transform("babelify", {"presets":["@babel/preset-env"]})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('script.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});
```

Comment: Share the relevant pieces of your gulp file. It could help solve the problem.